# How set context variable in a web app's context.xml when it's also the default web app?

Tags: java, tomcat, war, context.xml, server.xml

I have a WAR that I've set as the default web app in Tomcat's server.xml:

*Inside Server.xml*

```
<Host...>
    <Context docBase="mywar" path="" />
```

In addition, I have a `META-INF/context.xml` file where I set an environment variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context debug="0" reloadable="true">
    <Environment
            name="my.name"
            type="java.lang.String"
            value="donrhummy"
    />
</Context>
```

But it's throwing an exception `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name my.name is not bound in this Context`.

How can I get that context variable in my app?

*NOTE: That variable exists when I go to http://localhost/mywar*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i could find was:

1. Rename my WAR as `ROOT.war` (Case-sensitive)
2. Remove the `<Context...>` from server.xml

Tomcat will treat that as the root WAR (i.e. for the "/" path) and let it use the context form it's own `META-INF` directory.